# why this warning comes in making stand-alone .exe from my .m & .fig file ?

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, mcc, matlab-compiler

see i have one .m file & .fig file for gui feature associated with that .m file now for making standalone .exe file for that .m file

i am using

```
 mcc -m  -mv jig322.m jig322.fig
```

after doing this i get warning like this

```
Warning: No matching builtin function available for C:\MATLAB7\toolbox\simulink\simulink\set_param.bi
```

i am not getting why this warning comes ?

& after this all ma exe becomes ready but it doesn't work 100% by executing some function it gets crash ? 
why this all is happening here? how can i make my exe to better work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MathWorks Support](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-O9PX9/index.html?solution=1-O9PX9), you need to comment out the following two lines

```
set_param(0,'PaperType',defaultpaper);
set_param(0,'PaperUnits',defaultunits);
```

from `C:\MATLAB7\toolbox\compiler\deploy\matlabrc.m`

and then call `rehash toolboxcache` at the MATLAB prompt. See [the above link](http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-O9PX9/index.html?solution=1-O9PX9) for details.